# Less - compile only current file excluding imports

Tags: import, less

We have a third party less file in our project - say `foo.less`. `foo.less` will be compiled to `foo.css`.

```
foo.less
foo.css
-- team1.less
-- team1.css
-- team2.less
-- team2.css
```

`team1.less` and `team2.less` both import `foo.less`.
**Team1** has a reference to `foo.css` and `team1.css` 
on their web pages while 
**Team2** has a reference to `foo.css` and `team2.css`.

How can I get `team1.css` and `team2.css` to exclude `foo.css` in their respective compiled output? What is occurring right now is `team1.css` and `team2.css` both have `foo.css` in them (repetition of css code).

Edit: 
`team1.less` and `team2.less` imports `foo.less` to take advantage of a lot of variables and mixins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question to you is, why are you importing foo.less if you do not want it to be included?  If it's because you are using variables or mixins from foo.less, than you could separate those out into a separate less file, and import that instead.  That way there would not be any duplicate css.  This is good practice in general, that way you can reuse any variables/mixins without importing a bunch of css.

Comment: Added comment to question on why we are using the imports. It is not just variables but several mixins.

Comment: Than move those mixins and variables into a separate file, why the downvote?

Comment: The mixins can be any of the selectors defined in foo.less. Moving it all out would not be easy. So no other way out?

Comment: I don't think so, unless you had a separate process that removed any duplicate css from your output files.  See http://zmoazeni.github.io/csscss/

Answer (score 9):

### Now Available in LESS 1.5

You can import `foo.less` as a reference, like so:

```
@import (reference) "foo.less";
```

The code will be available for referencing variables, mixins, etc., but will not compile to css output.

Comment: Thanks *ScottS*. This is important for developers like myself who are building web frameworks. For instance, I have a 14KB "core" file that all of our web applications can use, but then we have platform/project specific additional styles that need to be loaded after for cache-ability. However, the core styles/mixins/variables should be able to be included in this additionally loaded specific CSS files. Very helpful, thanks a bunch!